# How to add button on Foreground Service Notification to Kill the Service on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I am building an app on Kotlin, and when I start my foreground service, I get a notification that it is running. How can I add a button to that notification, which when clicked by the user will terminate that foreground service?

```
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                "App Name",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            notificationManager!!.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }
    }

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("service", "Starting the foreground service")
        createNotificationChannel()
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId)
            .setContentTitle("App Notification")
            .setContentText("App is Running in the Forground")
            .build()
        startForeground(1, notification)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create pending intent then add actions in the notification builder. When the user clicked use broadcast receiver stop the service.

1. Create pending intent
2. Create Broadcast receiver

   ```
   .addAction(Drawable Icon, Action Name - "Dismiss",PendingIntent);
   ```

[More info](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)